# What is the best way to work with services in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, dependency-injection

I've just started a project on grails and didn't find how to work with services using dependency injection and interfaces.

As I've seen so far in the documentation when you create a service - it's just a groovy class which can be auto wired wherever I want.

But what if I want to have an interface for a service and to inject one of its implementation like I did in Java using spring?

eg I want to have a service interface. let it be MyService.groovy
it will have 1 method doSmth()
and I'll have 2 implementations - MyServiceImpl1.groovy and MyServiceImpl2.groovy

I have a quartz job doing something like this
def myService
myService.doSmth()

Where should I put groovy interface (folder)? Shall I create a package for that in src/groovy?
How to configure resources.groovy to wire "myService" with 1 of the service implementation?

Any thoughts are appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running `grails create-service [name]` is a convenient way of get a service deployed, but it doesn't create an interface with implementation, as you're looking for.

I'd suggest putting your interface and implementations into `src/groovy` and using `resources.groovy` to wire them up (you can access the environment, if you want to deploy a different implementation by environment).

Take a look at the 'Using the Spring DSL' section in [chapter 14.2 of the user guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html#14.2%20Configuring%20Additional%20Beans) for how to wire up your service in resources.groovy. You also have the option of using resources.xml if you want to wire with XML, but I'd definitely recommend the Groovy DSL.

Answer (score 0):

Just run grails create-service [name]

Comment: It will create a service class. I did that. the question is where to put an interface and how to use custom wiring.

Comment: The easiest answer is : put it in the same directory under the same package name